# gnuplot, break y-axis in two parts

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a histogram with some small values and some very big values. How can I break the y-axis in two parts?

EDIT:

[image]

gnuplot sample:

```
set style histogram columnstacked 
set style data histograms
set key autotitle columnheader
plot for [i=2:6] 'test.dat' using i
```

test.dat:

```
action device1 device2 device3
load    200 203 190 2 4
process 3 9 6 7 3
save    4 2 7 4 3
```

Comment: I believe you can manually specify `yticks`

Comment: ytics only specifies which labels are drawn next to the axis. It does not introduce ellipses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My answer is based on the example and comment on [this website](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.fr/2010/06/broken-axis-once-more.html). In essence, you are looking for a *broken y-axis*, which can be achieved using the `multiplot` option:

```
reset
unset key
bm = 0.15
lm = 0.12
rm = 0.95
gap = 0.03
size = 0.75
kk = 0.5 # relative height of bottom plot
y1 = 0.0; y2 = 15.0; y3 = 180.0; y4 = 220.0

set style histogram columnstacked 
set style data histograms
set key autotitle columnheader
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1

set multiplot
set border 1+2+8
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set lmargin at screen lm
set rmargin at screen rm
set bmargin at screen bm
set tmargin at screen bm + size * kk

set yrange [y1:y2]
plot for [i=2:6] 'test.dat' using i

unset xtics
unset xlabel
set border 2+4+8
set bmargin at screen bm + size * kk + gap
set tmargin at screen bm + size + gap
set yrange [y3:y4]

plot for [i=2:6] 'test.dat' using i

unset multiplot
```

Remarks:

- The first block of code specifies your plot size, as well as the two min/max for the y-axis range.
- The second block of code sets your histogram style. I suggest you used filled columns (else, you might get the wrong colors where the plot is cut off by the y-range).
- The third block starts you `multiplot` environment and sets up the lower plot (4th block).
- The fifth block of code defines you upper plot.
- To customize your plot, change the parameters in the first block (`bm`, `lm`, `rm`, `gap`, `size`, `kk` and `yi`)

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: At first glance it looks great. Thanks! Cannot test it right now, though. I'll report if it worked later.

Comment: This is not really intuitive, but ingenious! Works great! Thanks @Schorsch!